# Pairwise comparisons on bar plot. Matlab gramm toolbox

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I found some interesting package ([gramm](https://github.com/piermorel/gramm)), which improves Matlab graphics capabilities a lot. It is quite a new approach for me. I try to plot two bars, and indicate the significance between them. I have the following code:

```
N1 = 20;
N2 = 30;

A = randn(N1,1)*2+6;
B = randn(N2,1)*3+10;
X = [A;B];
grpID = [repmat({'A'},N1,1); repmat({'B'},N2,1)];
g = gramm('x',grpID,'y',X);
g.stat_summary('type','sem','geom',{'bar','black_errorbar'});
g.draw();
% Add pairwise comparison
g.update();

minX = nanmin(g.facet_axes_handles.Children(2).Vertices(:,1));
maxX = nanmax(g.facet_axes_handles.Children(2).Vertices(:,1));
maxBarHeight = max(g.facet_axes_handles.Children(2).Vertices(:,2));
maxY = nanmax(g.facet_axes_handles.Children(1).YData);
% Shift horizontal line to half difference between from max sem and max bar 
yLevel = maxY + (maxY - maxBarHeight);
plot(g.facet_axes_handles, [minX,maxX], [yLevel, yLevel]);
text(g.facet_axes_handles, mean([minX,maxX]), yLevel+0.1,'*','FontSize', 60)
```

It gives me the following plot:
[image]

I don't think that my way is correct in terms of the grammar of graphics.

Could You help me with some better solution for such kind of plots?

Comment: “improves Matlab graphics capabilities a lot” — some people feel this way, I don’t see the point of the grammar of graphics, it just complicates things. I also think that MATLAB makes some of the best graphs available, and your plot would be pretty trivial to generate using 3 or 4 lines of code. Would you be open to an answer that doesn’t use gramm?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Sure, I would be happy to see how to make such plot in 5 lines of pure Matlab Code